# Display and use Facebook in my_app after authorising the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

How to open Facebook and use them just like the 'friendly' app on iOS? My app has a Facebook login and when opened it says 'You have already authorised the app app_name'. Instead i want to display Facebook and use it just like the native app.

using objective c, Xcode 7 iOS 9.

I'm a newbie to Xcode and any help would be much appreciated. And by the way, thanks much in advance.

Comment: When you're not sure of the answer, please do not down-vote as this has much demand in public.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph)

You can use Graph API to get all the user activity, but you need the user permission for that.

First you need to submit all the permissions you want for Facebook review and wait for the approval.

And then to get the user timeline you do like that:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:nil]
startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,   id result, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
     NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
  }
}];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But can you please be more elaborate. Since i'm not sure of how this can be implemented.

Comment: :@ryniere:  i've got the user permission. i've done that part. 
My question is that how to use Facebook just like the native or browser app instead of only authorising or signing up through fb.

Comment: Mate, you need to implement all the facebook features. Its not magic. You get the data from facebook API and display to the user.

Comment: And do you have all the permissions? because you need all in order to recreate the Facebook app.

Comment: this is not i'm talking about pal. 
Check out the 'friendly' app from App store. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/friendly-social-login-multiple/id400169658?mt=8 I need something like this, opening the Facebook itself from my_app not only the permissions.

Comment: I see, use a UIWebView then, and call the mobile facebook site.

Comment: When you're not sure of the answer, please do not down-vote as this has much demand in public